# Is there a way to flag profiles?

Tags: support, flagging, profile-page, display-names

[This username](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/782164/killer-of-jews) is clearly inappropriate for this site (or really any other, frankly). Normally I would flag one of the user's posts, but they don't have any; **is there a way to flag a user profile directly**? If not, what should one do instead?

Admittedly, one possible response is that in a situation where the user hasn't made any posts to flag, there's no reason to feed the troll by even acknowledging their profile. However, I don't personally agree with that as a universal (and in particular I don't buy it in the specific situation above).

Comment: This username goes far beyond trolling.

Comment: @amWhy I agree of course.

Comment: The username has "changed" since your post here (to user46548).  Worth keeping an eye on it, though.

Comment: @amWhy And now it's gone.

Comment: Thank goodness!  Thanks for posting here!

Comment: I just stumbled upon this post, from another site. Could we edit this post to exclude the username from the hyperlink. On mouse-over it still shows the past username. Since the profile is now deleted please link to only the usernumber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question and answer on meta.stackexchange.com gives a solution:

[Reporting an inappropriate or offensive user name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213180)

I think it applies to all the SE sites:

> Flag a question/answer/comment by such a user for moderator attention as "Other".
>
> Explain you are flagging due to their name/avatar/about me section being offensive to you.
>
> If you cannot find any post of this user, use the [contact us link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the footer of each page to inform Stack Exchange staff - linking to their profile.

Comment: Oh thanks, I missed that question - I only searched for e.g. "flagging profiles" or similar.

Answer (score 7):

> is there a way to flag a user profile directly?

There isn't, only posts and comments can be flagged.

> If not, what should one do instead?

Besides using the [contact](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link, you can also flag one of your posts and explain the situation (include a link to the problematic profile). This may, especially on weekends, lead to a faster reaction than the contact link (staff usually has weekends off, some volunteer moderator tends to be available also through the weekends).

Thanks for bringing this one to our attention.

Comment: And of course, one can always come on the chat and try and ping a moderator...